# Prevent JavaScript Console Bots

Tags: javascript, bots

I have a chat where all users are able to - globally - guess on a number between 1 and 1000 during a *giveaway*. My problem is that some users are using **JavaScript Console Bots**. Meaning, they can interpret when a user is guessing and therefor have a much bigger chance of winning themselves.

Lets say User 1 is using a bot. The bot starts immediately guessing when the giveaway starts, randomizing numbers and sending them to the chat. When the bot has used a number, it saves it in a **tried list**. When User 2 guesses on a number, the User 1's bot saves that too in the **tried list**.

I am using the [isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) property, but that doesn't stop it. I have thought about disabling the Console, but that is not recommended, and not even possible anymore. I have also thought about obscuring all the chat messages during the *giveaway*, but that is not fun at all.

What approach should I take? Any ideas?

Comment: You can perhaps implement the chat feature using something; the insides of which, cannot be traversed via the DOM - like a flash app or a java applet

Comment: Wait, do you mean that each user can try as many times as they want? So if **User1** is guessing, they can try `1`, `14`, and `17` while **User2** can try, say, `3` and `12`?

Comment: @vlaz Each user can try as many times as they want, correct.

Comment: @techfoobar I do not want to use flash or java applet. The chat/website is supported by mobile phones at the moment, and I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: @FredrikL so-o-o, it doesn't really seem like a bot problem. Or rather, it rather it does, but not for the reason specified. What's stopping somebody from just guessing all the numbers in a second by spamming using a script/bot/whatever? If you allow each user a limited amount of guesses, then bots and cheating in general become way less of a problem. You can't really have a fair competition where users are inherently treated unfairly - you are also penalising users who type slower or have higher latency or whatever.

Comment: @vlaz As of now, users are limited to 1 try per second. I don't want to limit the amount of guesses. That would eventually make the chat "dead", since no users might not have any guesses left. It's supposed to be a bit "skill" by typing fast and having a certain strategy. Latency is a problem, yes. However, it is a rather small issue in my opinion.

Comment: @FredrikL then perhaps you merely need to hide the numbers until after the competition is done. Again, I don't believe this to be a bot problem as you can't really secure against it while still having the data for the a successful cheat available. If you somehow manage to block user-side JS cheating (which is unlikely), then the same can be achieved by using a screen reader and an automated typer. Or a web scraper. Point is, you can't have both the means to cheat and prevent cheating. Perhaps change the chat messages to mask the digits, e.g., \* instead of 4. You can reveal them afterwards.

Comment: @vlaz It seems like that is the way to go, hiding the message. Thanks for the help. If you come up with something else, don't hesitate posting it :)